# node.js package ("mongoose") ErrorConnet

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
error: MongoNetworkError: 581F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80

            at connectionFailureError (C:\src\blog-diary\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:367:20)
            at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\src\blog-diary\api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:290:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:629:26)
            at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
            at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
          cause: [Error: 581F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80
          ] {
            library: 'SSL routines',
            reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
            code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
          },
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' }
        },
        topologyVersion: null,
        setName: null,
        setVersion: null,
        electionId: null,
        logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
        primary: null,
        me: null,
        '$clusterTime': null
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-9t99d2-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

Who knows the problem and how to fix it?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What version of Node.js are you running?

Comment: I am using node.js version 18.17.1 @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing indicates a problem with SSL/TLS encryption while trying to connect to a MongoDB server.

Check Your MongoDB Connection String

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@clustername.mongodb.net/databaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&sslCAPath=path-to-ca-file.pem
```

Comment: Check My MongoDB Connection String
Yes I try but noting